# Go benchmark run from main / go playground

Tags: go

I am trying to create a suite of benchmark tests

https://play.golang.org/p/uWWITU-WKaL

package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
)

func runall(a, b string) (bool, error) {
    return true, nil
}

func main() {
    bench := []testing.InternalBenchmark{
        {
            F: Benchmark_Dev,
        },
    }

    tests := []testing.InternalTest{
        {
            F: Test_Dev,
        },
    }
    testing.Main(runall, tests, bench, nil)
}

func Test_Dev(t *testing.T) {
    fmt.Println("Test_Dev")
}

func Benchmark_Dev(b *testing.B) {
    fmt.Println("Benchmark_Dev")
    b.ReportAllocs()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        res := i % 10
        fmt.Println(res)
    }
}
```

I see Tests are run fine, but the benchmarks are never run.

Comment: "are never run" is not a useful problem description. What did you actually do and what happened? Forgot -bench?

Comment: I am not attempting to run as tests either. In the suite, there are both tests and benchmark why only tests are run?

Comment: @Kamath use [testing.Benchmark](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#Benchmark) for benchmarks that do not use "go test"

Comment: This is all wrong. Please read what `go doc testing.Main` has to say. Just run your benchmark via `go test -run X -bench .*`

Comment: Thanks, @mkopriva this works, https://play.golang.org/p/R3_lcL7GZKk if you post it answer I will accept it. However, I am still wondering why testing.Main doesn't work https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#Main seems like it's depreciated

Comment: @Kamath Main and StartMain are both exported only because they are used by more than one package in the std lib, however, as indicated by their documentation, they are not intended to be imported by other packages and used the way you would like. Do not use them!

Answer (score 7):

If you read ["About" on Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/):

> If the program contains tests or examples and no main function, the service runs the tests. Benchmarks will likely not be supported since the program runs in a sandboxed environment with limited resources.

You will find your answer

Comment: Ok agreed from playground, how can I run benchmarks from main ?

Comment: Hm. I don't understand: why don't you want usual way: `go test -bench=.` ?

Comment: How would you fail the tests if benchmark results exceed a threshold?

Comment: I think it's another question. AFAIK there is no flags to test iteration duration. We have `go test -bench .  -benchtime N` but it garantees that benchmark will run **at least** N seconds. It does not mark test as `FAIL`ed in case of longer duration. So if you need such kind tests - you are free to implement them. Maybe you will find your solution with [ginkgo](https://onsi.github.io/ginkgo/#benchmark-tests)